# Pass variable from php to javascript function (desktop notification)

Tags: javascript, php, notifications, desktop

Need one more litle help.
I want to pass my variable from php to javascript function with desktop notification. But how i try still cant get it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function notifyMe(lol) {
  var v = lol;

  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Please us a modern version of Chrome, Firefox, Opera or Firefox.');
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();

  var notification = new Notification('Jums sukurta nauja užduotis!', {
    icon: 'task.png',
    body: v,
    timeout: 3000,
    tag: '24',
  });
}
</script>
<?php

$id = "123";
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">var lol = $id </script>';
    echo '<button id="myLink" onclick="notifyMe(lol)">Notify me!</button>';


?>
```

Comment: In button onclick work onclick="notifyMe('.$id.')" this one, but dont work when call just function echo '<script type="text/javascript">notifyMe('.$id.');</script>'; I think bad send argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
echo '<button id="myLink" onclick="notifyMe(lol)">Notify me!</button>';
```

to

```
echo '<button id="myLink" onclick="notifyMe('.$id.')">Notify me!</button>';
```

In your script you are actually sending "lol" as text, not the value of $ID. You can check this by right clicking on the browser after you have loaded the html, and displaying the source code. Find this line and check that it is doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: One more thing, how pass few variables? Something like that? ('.$date. + .$name. + .$task.')

Comment: In essence you are using php to generate the text as if you were writing the function direct. Try writing out the function in it's final form, and then work backwards to work out what php is required to create that text. Re multiple variables, I expect it would be something like: ...('.$date.','.$name.','.$task')... Note the commas inside quotes - you separate  function parameters with quotes so you need to also create them with php.

Answer (score 0):

Put your PHP variable in an hidden input and then read that input value using JavaScript selector